# AngularJS redirect to home page after login not working

Tags: angularjs, html, spring-mvc, spring-security

My application is with spring + angularJS and after authentication from controller i am not able to redirect to home page.

```
console.log("id:"+employee.id);     

alert("Trying to redirect to home page");
$location.path("/home/"+employee.id);
```

When this gets executed http://localhost:9393/login#/home/21 is being redirected in the url but i want  http://localhost:9393/home/21 (without /login#)

Comment: you should show your config file of your router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because $location is using Hashbang URL, you can change this by enabling Html5Mode .
[enter image description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

So include this in .config method of your module.

```
locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

For more details look here [AngularJS Guide for $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Answer (score 2):

The hash is because of the hashbang mode. you will have to configure html5 mode. This tutorial explains how to enable html5mode (pretty url)
[HTML 5 Mode- angularJs](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)

For more details look here [AngularJS Guide for $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Comment: The Plunker of the whole code is there with JS.
https://plnkr.co/edit/BtJhAI?p=info

Comment: I don't see any route defined. You will have to define the routes. Learn about them here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: I just need to redirect them from login page as user is authenticated in spring controller and id is passed to angular so just redirect the user with the id  http://localhost:9393/login to http://localhost:9393/home/21 is enough. Do we need angular route for this

Comment: In that case, you can just use window.location. You will have to go through the vanilla javascript way.

Comment: Using pure old javascript which am trying redirects to http://localhost:9393/login#/home/21 but i want http://localhost:9393/home/21. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Instead of using `$location.path`, can you use `$location.url` and try ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102590/discussion-between-vikram-and-ashfaq-p).